# How to work with BufferedImage and YCbCr colorspace?

Tags: java, colors, bufferedimage

I need to translate colors in bitmap loaded to BufferedImage from RGB to YCbCr (luminance and 2 channels chrominance) and back after process.

I made it with functions used like rgb2ycbcr() in main method for each pixel, but it isn't so smart solution. I should use ColorSpace and ColorModel classes to get BufferedImage with correct color space. It would be more flexible method, but I don't know how to do that.

I'm lost and I need some tips. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood your question, you want to do the following:

**Load RGB image** -> *process YCbCr image* -> **Use RGB image again**

And you want us to help you, to make this process as seamless as possible. First and foremost you want us to give you a simple way to avoid the `->` (converting) parts.

Well I looked into the [`BufferedImage` documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). It seems, as if there doesn't exist a way to change the `ColorSpace` of an once created `BufferedImage`.

You could create a new `BufferedImage` with an YCbCr color space for that you can use the predefined [`ICC_ColorSpace`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/color/ICC_ColorSpace.html). Then you copy the data from your old image possibly via `ColorSpace.fromRGB` to the YCbCr color space, do the image processing and then convert again via `ColorSpace.toRGB`. This method requires you to fully convert the image before and after processing via existing methods. Furthermore you have to know, how `ICC_ColorSpace` converts your image to YCbCr color space. Otherwise you can't know, which array indices corresponds to the same pixel.

If you just want to create a wrapper around the RGB-`BufferedImage` that lets you manipulate this image, as if it was an YCbCr image, that isn't possible with `BufferedImage`.

EDIT:
To convert the color space of a `BufferedImage` use [`ColorConvertOp`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html). The code would look something like this:

```
ColorConvertOp cco = new ColorConvertOp(new YCbCrColorSpace(), null);
BufferedImage ycbcrImage = cco.filter( oldRGBImage, null );
```

This requires you to either write your own `ColorSpace` class or you could download and use the classes mentioned [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=623646). If you just want to load a JPEG image you should use the [predefined classes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html).

Comment: But I still don't know how to do that. I'm lost and I can find anything above documentation of classes. This is so different from static functions. Any examples?

I'm writing implementation of JPEG algorithm and I need to convert to YCbCr and separate channels before fragmentation. Now I'm working with many arrays and function. This is not so flexible as I want.

Comment: Maybe the `BufferedImage` class is not what you're looking for. If you just want your procedural Jpeg (de-)encoder to make more OOP-like try something else. One possibility is to make a class for every step of the Jpeg (de-)encodeing pipeline.

Comment: Ok. From the beginning :)
I need to open image, separate Y, Cb, Cr channels and fragment each channel before compression.
So I need BufferedImage with getY(), getCb, getCr() methods or three with one channel for each. How to do that?

Comment: Don't use `BufferedImage` for that. Either you write your own class doing what you want or use [`WritableRaster`][1] use the documentation of [`Raster`][2] to see, how the pixels are stored. Because this discussion to this answer gets ridiculously long, this will be my last comment here.


  [1]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html
  [2]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html